# cloud 9 and laravel5.1 not displaying validation error

Tags: laravel-5.1, cloud9-ide

new to laravel and experimenting on an ordering app using cloud9 and laravel5.1 . I was able to create authentication and make the ordering work. but my problem is when I try to login or register with the wrong credentials the error message is not displaying, and sometimes it shows up out of the blue.. does the https or http matters when laravel tries to redirect? you can view the full source code here: https://github.com/2n2n/food4lunch

you can try it by visiting this link: https://food4lunch-a2n2n-2.c9.io/

Comment: Is there anything in your logs?

Comment: nope nothing... I also installed bugsnap, to check the errors but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of simply using `redirect()`, try using:

```
redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath(), 302, [], true);
```

to force **Laravel** to send as `HTTPS`. if it works then the issue is on redirect.